# How to pass integer values in cucumber test and verify the result

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cucumberjs

How do I call a simple addition function and assert the result of two values using [selenium-cucumber-js](https://github.com/john-doherty/selenium-cucumber-js) framework with a test written below. While running the below it says 
TypeError:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'addvalues' of undefined
at createWorld.When (C:\Tests\cucumber\step-definitions\addvalues-steps.js:5:25)

```
Feature:
 Scenario: Addition of two values   
        When Add two values 5 and 10
        Then I should get result 15
```

// Here is my 'addvalues-steps.js' file

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;
module.exports = function () {  

    this.When(/^Add two values (-?\d+) and (-?\d+)$/, (x, y) =>{
        this.page.addvalues.addValues(x,y); 
    })

    this.Then(/^I should get result (-?\d+)$/, (ans) =>{
    let tot =  this.page.addvalues.addValues(x, y); 
        expect(tot).to.be.eql(ans);     
    })
};
```

// Following is my 'addvalues.js file'

```
module.exports = {    
   addValues(x,y){
    var total = x + y ;   
    return  total ;        
     }  
};
```

// world.js >>

```
const { CustomWorld } = require('cucumber')
function CustomWorld() {
    console.log('overriding the world')
    this.page = {
        addvalues: require('../page-objects/addvalues')
    }
    console.log("This is the recent error log:"+this.page.addvalues)        

}

module.exports = function() {
    this.World = CustomWorld;
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show where you define `page` that you're accessing as `this.page`? Probably in your `World` object?

Comment: The World.js file sits under the support folder... `const { setWorldConstructor } = require('cucumber')
class page {
  constructor() {
  this.variable = 0
  }  
  addValues(x,y) {
    this.variable = x 
 this.variable = y 
  }  
}
setWorldConstructor(page)`

Comment: one more thing: can you add your project structure and the command you're using to run cucumber?

Comment: From windows command prompt : 
`C:\Tests\cucumber>npm test`

Comment: if it's `npm test`, what's in your `package.json` then?

Comment: In the package.json file....`"scripts": {
    "test": "node ./node_modules/selenium-cucumber-js/index.js -s ./step-definitions -x 50000"
  }`

Comment: I was using the same command `npm test` and successfully running with other cucumber tests earlier

Comment: Added the project structure too

Comment: oh man... *now* I get it. You've been using `selenium-cucumber-js` all this time... I guess I'll update my answer again

Comment: Yes i am using selenium-cucumber-js

Comment: There, I've edited the answer. You can undo all the edits you've done to the `world.js`

Comment: yey ! ..its passing my test now, awesome help shkaper !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note**: the below example is for an old version of cucumber-js: 1.3.3. 
With cucumber.js, when you're referencing `this` from inside step definitions, you're actually referencing the World context. So, for `this.page.addvalues.addValues(x,y);` to work properly, you'll first need to create `page` that has a reference to your `addvalues.js`. Something along these lines:

**world.js:**

```
function CustomWorld() {
    console.log('overriding the world')
    this.page = {
        addvalues: require('../page-objects/addvalues')
    }
}

module.exports = function() {
    this.World = CustomWorld;
};
```

**addvalues.js:**

```
//addvalues.js
module.exports = {
    addValues(x,y){
        var total = x + y ;
        return  total ;
    }
};
```

There's also a couple of things to correct in your `steps.js`.

1. Don't pass arrow functions into the steps, as this will remove the `this` context that you're setting in World.js.
2. If you want to share variables between steps (as you do in your example), you need to store them somewhere. One such place, again, would be the World context. Note how in my version I set `this.prevResult`
3. When the variables are injected into your steps, they are injected as strings. Note the `parseInt()` in my version.

**addvalues-steps.js:**

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;

module.exports = function() {
    this.When(/^Add two values (-?\d+) and (-?\d+)$/, function (x, y) {
        this.prevResult = this.page.addvalues.addValues(parseInt(x, 10), parseInt(y, 10));
    })

    this.Then(/^I should get result (-?\d+)$/, function (ans) {
        let tot = this.prevResult;
        expect(tot).to.be.eql(parseInt(ans, 10));
    })
}
```

---

**UPD:** It turns out that the question is about [selenium-cucumber-js](https://github.com/john-doherty/selenium-cucumber-js), which is a framework on top of `cucumber-js`. Disregard the comments about the `world.js`.

According to `selenium-cucumber-js` docs, you don't need `this` to access the page objects in your step definitions:

> Page objects are accessible via a global page object and are
>   automatically loaded from `./page-objects`.

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;

module.exports = function() {
    this.When(/^Add two values (-?\d+) and (-?\d+)$/, function (x, y) {
        this.prevResult = page.addvalues.addValues(parseInt(x, 10), parseInt(y, 10));
    })

    this.Then(/^I should get result (-?\d+)$/, function (ans) {
        let tot = this.prevResult;
        expect(tot).to.be.eql(parseInt(ans, 10));
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added the `world.js` under the support folder as per above. Now the constructor looks as below: But still gives error; 
`const { setWorldConstructor } = require('cucumber')
class CustomWorld {
  constructor() {
    this.page = {
      addvalues: require('../page-objects/addvalues.js')
    }
  }
    addValues(x, y) {
    this.variable = x
 this.variable = y
  }
}
setWorldConstructor(CustomWorld)`

Comment: @soccerway which version of`cucumber.js are you using?

Comment: When I run `npm cucumber -version` from command prompt ..It gives me  `3.10.10`

Comment: this way you're actually getting the version of npm itself. try `npm list cucumber` instead

Comment: After running as per you advised `selenium-cucumber-js@1.6.2  cucumber@1.3.3`

Comment: @soccerway I've updated my answer. Btw, your cucumber version is really old, you might want to consider upgrading.

Comment: Appreciate your efforts, but this is still throws error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'addvalues' of undefined at createWorld.<anonymous> (C:\Tests\cucumber\step-definitions\addvalues-steps.js:4:36) at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
 at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)` 1)  I have added `world.js` under the features\support folder 2) Added `const { CustomWorld } = require('cucumber')` in the start of world.js file  3) addvalues.js file under page-objects folder 4) addvalues-steps.js file under \step-definitions folder

Comment: did you change arrow functions to `function () {}` in your addvalues-steps.js?

Comment: Yes I did change the arrow function to `function () {}`

Comment: can you add `console.log(this.page.addvalues)` after `this.page = { addvalues: require('../page-objects/addvalues')  }` and share the output?

Comment: Do you know where the console error will log ..in command prompt ? or some where else ?

Comment: What do you mean? node.js outputs `console.error()` into process' stderr: https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_error_data_args

Comment: `Message:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'addvalues' of undefined
         at createWorld.<anonymous> (C:\Tests\cucumber\step-definitions\addvalues-steps.js:4:36)
         at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
         at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
         at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
         at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)`
5 scenarios (1 failed, 4 passed)
10 steps (1 failed, 1 skipped, 8 passed)

Comment: can you share your `world.js` code? you can add it into the question

Comment: Added the world.js to the question

Comment: Well, you're requiring something that `cucumber` doesn't export: `const { CustomWorld } = require('cucumber')`. Please take a look at what's in my answer's `world.js` and replace the whole contents of your `world.js`.

Comment: If that's not it - I've ran out of ideas. I have the whole thing replicated on my machine and it just works. The 3 files I have are all in my answer.